# Why is the original version of my app continually being disitrbuted on Google Play even after updating it?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have build an Android app with react-native and I am trying to distribute it on Google Play, but the APK that I uploaded the first time continues to be dstribued while other information updates on Google Play such as version number, and the release description. When I then download the app, I get the original version and not the recently uploaded version. To do this I take the following steps:

1. start Android Studio, delete the old build folder;
2. in react-native project root folder, I run react-native run-android;
3. set a new version build > edit flavors;
4. click build > Generate signed APK, go through the steps and build succeeds;
5. go into Google Play, create a new release, update release information upload the APK and wait 10 minutes for the changes to take place;
6. delete old version of the app from my device, download the new version;
7. boom, the old version starts up on my device.

Why do I keep downloading the original version when these steps taken has not changed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to run and check the app on the emulator before generating the APK? If so, does it work properly? And is every element of your app inside the APK or does it use external connections to run?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, two things pop up in my mind:

- check whether you are really uploading a new version because you may be uploading the same APK as the release build you're taking can be an old package rather than the updated one (I guess the new generated build started to be delivered in a different folder last year) or even you're importing an outdated version from the other platform;
- maybe a new `android:minSdkVersion` isn't enough for your device or your device isn't compatible with new features of your updated APK (although I'm not sure about how Google Play would deal with such a situation: would they deliver an old compatible version and show the info about a new incompatible one or would they simply not show you the app on the store at all if a new version is incompatible with your device?).

I'd also recommend you to keep the old version on your phone while installing the new one to be sure you're really updating it to the new version of the app rather than downloading an old version since it usually takes way longer than 10 minutes to updates roll out.

Comment: Thanks, I think it has somthing to do with googleplay actually because. The file that I upload is 9.2 mb, and then as soon as it is uploaded, the file is 8.8 ... maybe there is some sort of compression occuring though.

Comment: Also I Have deleted the build folder in the react-native project, I run react-native run-android... And this problem has been existent for days... So I feel like the apks that I uploaded just a couple days ago would be showing up by now...

Comment: I dont think point 2 is relevent because I am not adding any new features that would be incompatible..

Comment: You're welcome! Being a Google Play store issue, I'd suggest you to report a bug if possible. And even the first point isn't that strong because you wouldn't be allowed to upload a new version with the same number unless you're sending the same code from React and just updating the number on Android Studio. But it's really weird and these were my thoughts about the problem because sometimes we miss simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play support are free, good and helpful. They can see all the details about your app too. I suggest contacting them is the best option. Just use the question mark icon for "help" then choose "contact us". In some countries at some times of day they have live chat, other countries and other times of day they have email support.

I suspect you just aren't waiting long enough, changes can take a lot longer than 10 minutes to roll out.